# Is there a way to make PC game pass installs and updates continue after a Windows reboot?

Tags: xbox-game-pass

I sometimes like to start game installs on more traditional platforms like Steam, GoG, Origin, Ubisoft Connect etc. right before I shut down my PC for the night so that when I boot my PC the next morning, the download will immediately resume where it left off. The problem I have is that if I try this on PC Game Pass games, it will not resume the download where I left off. I need to restart the download from scratch, and I even have reason to suspect that if I do this with pending updates for already installed games, it will flag the game as not installed, but without removing the game files that were already installed, leaving what can sometimes be tens of gigabytes on my hard drive that aren't easily removed.

Is there a way to suspend a PC Game Pass install or update in a way that will automatically resume the update where I left off the next time the PC boots?